Download rabssm/Radiometer from Git Hub
enter code hereI wish to install Radiometer Lux meter from Git Hub.
https://github.com/rabssm/Radiometer
This is specifically for Raspberry Pi
I have clean install of 32 bit Debian Bullseye (as in the readme)
Using the pip install code supplied does not install the main program 'radiometer_tsl2591.py'
pip install RPi.GPIO
pip install board
pip install adafruit-extended-bus
pip install adafruit-circuitpython-tsl2591
pip install flask    # For the REST API

I think there is a main program somewhere but unable to find how to download it.
Has anyone experience of this or alternatively is there a git hub forum I should use?

the fact that you didn't try pip install -r requirements.txt suggests you haven't even bothered to download the code from that git repo

I don't have the necessary hardware to run this code.
The steps should look something like this.
Make sure you have git tools installed.
sudo apt install git

Make a clone of the repository with the code.
git clone git@github.com:rabssm/Radiometer.git

Go to the project directory and install dependencies.
cd Radiometer
pip install -r requirements.txt

Go to the directory with the executable file and run it.
cd src
python radiometer_tsl2591.py


Yes I tried pip install -r requirements.txt but only did what the individual lines of code did.
What I am missing is how to get the code from Github.(I have even successfully somehow installed this before in another Pi)
Do I install each of the files from SRC?
This is basic I know.
Thanks for your patience
